# Create new repo and have all the 'old" repo files in the new one

Tags: git

I have an existing repository that almost hit the 2G limits.
I need to try for the first try to shrink it as much as I can in the way that I will make the old deleted files history to be deleted and therefor I will have some more free space in the repository.

I want to have my first try doing that on a copy of the old repository that I will have in a new repository that I created.

Since I do not know GIT very well and I afraid to damaged the existing repository I asking for any help that you can send to me in order to see how all the setups that needs to be done actually goes and as a side affect I will see how much free space I will have due this process.

I tried to follow this guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html but I really afraid doing that by my self with no help.
Thanks again for your help.

I crated a copy of the "old" repository and backed it up in other folder.

Comment: You can always clone your repo and resize it locally (the clone is not even necessary actually) and if you are satisfied by the work in local then you can push it to the remote repository.

Comment: You could copy your working copy and delete the `.git` folder inside that, then run `git init`. This will however delete all of the history, branches, ...

Comment: @desmaxi You're assuming there is a "remote" repository.

Comment: @melpomene yes indeed ... He could always copy/paste the .git folder in a new repository to maintain the history

Answer (score 0):

You can do a tarball export and initialize the new repository there

```
cd old_repo #Wherever your git repository is
mkdir ../new_repo

#The following line copies over the files from your existing repository with 
#.git files and repository history etc

git archive master | tar -x -C ../new_repo 

cd ../new_repo

# Delete any files you want 

git init .
git add -A
git commit -a

# Create a new git repository on atlassian or github
git remote add origin <new_repo_url_from_atlassian_or_github>
git push -u origin master # or any other branch
```